# Access Related Module Entries in SugarCRM, using JAVA AXIS SOAP Client

Tags: java, soap, axis, sugarcrm

I have a one to many relationship between 2 custom modules.

For each entry in Module 1, I want to be able to fetch the entries in Module 2, related to it.

I tried get_Relationships function, but the return type is get_relationships_result.

How do i access the records??

Answer (score 0):

You can this sample code

`$get_params = array(
      'session' => $this->sessionID,
      'module_name' => $rel_data['name'],
      'module_id' => $rel_data['id'],
      'related_module' => $rel_data['rel_module'],
      'related_module_query' => $query,
      'deleted' => 0,
 );
 $entry_result = $this->client->call('get_relationships', $get_params);`

This will return related IDs.